# Is there a Hub that can receive a 915Mhz signal and report on it?

Tags: smart-home, raspberry-pi, sensors

I'm looking for a device that can detect (and report to my raspberry pi) the presence of a signal from my Switcheroo:

Switcheroo - Sync Lights with No App, WiFi, Bluetooth, or Remote Control | Change Which Outlets Turn On/Off with Your Existing Light Switch | Smart Outlet Solution for Multiple Plug Switches (2-Pack) [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BX6QF7Q/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_i_PQZ4ATQ7S1BK81EQC2RS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BX6QF7Q)

I suspect that it transmits on the 915Mhz band. (The device designer stated in a Q&A that it operates at 900Mhz, but I assume he was just being imprecise - and I asked to confirm that assumption on the product listing.)

I guess I'm basically looking for a 915Mhz hub that can detect the signal and report its presence/absence to my Pi, so I can know when it turns on or off.

Incidentally, I'm really looking for an answer to this specific question and not some underlying question, because I like to tinker. I'm not looking for other ways to achieve something else.

Answer (score 2):

While you've said you're not looking for a general solution but you are probably going to end up using an SDR (Software Defined Radio).

While there are USB 915Mhz receivers (e.g. https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32378710247.html) they cost the same as basic receive only SDR capable hardware (https://www.nooelec.com/store/sdr/sdr-receivers/nesdr/nesdr-smart-sdr.html). The SDR approach also means that should the device not actually be 915Mhz the ability to chase the device round the spectrum will be easier. You are also more likely to find help from the SDR community in getting this all to work.

p.s. I'm not actively recommending any of the hardware linked, they are purely examples.

Comment: Do SDRs exist that pick up multiple channels at once?  I plan to have 3 pairs of Switcheroos and it would be nice to have a single hub that reports on all 3.  I'm guessing no, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: They will all be on the same radio channel, just with device ids in the message so the SDR won't matter. And the fun thing about an SDR is they can basically listen to whole blocks of frequencies at the same time, due to how they work,

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how I would incorporate this into what I'm hoping to accomplish. I know virtually nothing about SDR (and not much about the Switcheroo signals/channels). I use an IR hub and a 433mhz transmitter/receiver with pilight, but only just to send codes. I haven't used my 433 receiver except to learn codes. I watched this: (https://youtu.be/7pgCC4cqgTc) to learn a bit. If all the switcheroo channels are just changing embedded codes on the same freq, can you refer me to a resource that can show me how to learn those codes and trigger things to happen when they appear/disappear?

Comment: Are you sure the switcheroo "channels" are just changing embedded codes? Wouldn't 2 switcheroo transmitters being "on" (using different "channels") interfere with one another?  I assume they're using on/off encoding, but I don't know.  And I know from a bug I reported in pilight that mixed codes cause things to get scrambled, and the signals to not work.

Comment: Though I guess listening to a "block" of frequencies should resolve that concern if it does use different frequencies/channels.

Comment: They do not continuously transmit, they will only send messages on state change. I suggest you read up on things like the gqrx for using an sdr with Linux.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure that's true.  I *know* that the Quirky Switchflip (I have 2 pairs) sends a continuous signal, and it makes sense that the Switcheroo works the same way, because how could it send the off signal with no power? I'll read the doc again to confirm, but thanks - I'll look for the gqrx doc.

Comment: It seems the answer to that is somewhere in the middle. I spoke to the guy who developed the Switcheroo. He said that it repeatedly (as opposed to continuously) sends an "on" signal. It also has a capacitor that allows it to send an "off" signal when power is cut. The capacitor has enough charge to send a few signals, but it has a timeout as a backup mechanism for "off" if it hasn't received the "on" signal in awhile.

Comment: I read a bit about the basics of `gqrx`. I'm not sure, but it seems geared toward listening to (& graphically viewing) broadcasts & operates in a GUI. As I'm learning about how the Switcheroo works, I'm beginning to think employing an SDR/gqrx might be a misapplication, or at least overkill. I think what I need may be something akin to running pilight & installing a 915Mhz receiver on my breadboard. pilight only works w/ 433, & I've only used my receiver to learn codes, but pilight can listen for specific codes & be used to trigger actions. I haven't seen anything in gqrx that speaks to that.